# how to plot a groupby using plotly and streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, pandas-groupby, streamlit

I have a dataframe consist of 3 columns I want to plot the crosstab result of 3 columns

I am able until now to plot bar chart of grouping 2 columns. on jupyter notebook **without using of streamlit**

when i try to use streamlit it display the below error:

```
TypeError: add_trace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'trace'
```

So where is the error in my code ??

## code:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go

#create a canvas for each item
interactive =  st.beta_container()

df =pd.DataFrame({"source_number":[11199,11328,11287,32345,12342,1232,13456,123244,1235],
       "location":["loc1","loc2","loc3","loc1","loc1","loc2","loc3","loc2","loc1"],
       "category":["cat1","cat3","cat1","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat1"],
       }) 

all_columns_names= df.columns.tolist()
selected_column_names = st.multiselect("select column to plot",all_columns_names)

s = df[selected_column_names[0]].str.strip().value_counts()


with interactive:
    fig = go.Figure
    for name,group in df.groupby(selected_column_names[0]):
        trace =go.Histogram()
        trace.name = name 
        trace.x = group[selected_column_names[1]]
        fig.add_trace(trace)
    fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably more going on here, but you're missing `()` in `fig = go.Figure()` here:

```
with interactive:
    fig = go.Figure
    for name,group in df.groupby(selected_column_names[0]):
```